# System of recurrence relations with different even and odd relations

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I know the following:

if n is even, then: $A_{n+1}=A_n+B_n$ and $B_{n+1}=B_n$

if n is odd, then it is the reverse: $A_{n+1}=A_n$ and $B_{n+1}=A_n+B_n$

I am given the initial conditions that $A_1=A_2=B_1=1$ and $B_2=2$

I've solved recurrence relations before, but this has two going at once with each dependent on the other so I'm not sure what to do. I can code it out well enough, but I'm trying to get a closed form instead of a recurrence. I would appreciate a solution if anyone could demonstrate how to tackle this.

Answer (score 3):

Assume $n$ is even. Then, you have
$A_{n+2} = A_{n+1} = A_{n}+B_{n}$,
$B_{n+2} = A_{n+1}+B_{n+1} = A_{n}+2B_{n}$

Combining them, you can get $A_{n+4} = 3A_{n+2} - A_{n}$ and solve it as usual one.

Once you get closed form of $A_{n}$, you can do similar step for $B_{n}$ or substitute the closed form into $B_{n}=A_{n+2}-A_{n}$.

Then you can do similar step for odd $n$, or substitute the closed form of even cases into the reccurence relation.

Answer (score 2):

In such problems it rarely hurts to gather some numerical evidence to see if an answer suggests itself, especially if you don’t see any better approach. It’s not hard to calculate the following table:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
n&A_n&B_n\\\hline
1&1&1\\
2&1&2\\
3&3&2\\
4&3&5\\
5&8&5\\
6&8&13\\
7&21&13
\end{array}$$

The numbers $A_n$ and $B_n$ are easily recognizable as Fibonacci numbers. In fact, we can expand the table as follows:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
n&A_n&B_n\\\hline
1&1=\color{red}{F_2}&1=\color{red}{F_1}\\
2&1=\color{red}{F_2}&2=F_3\\
3&3=F_4&2=F_3\\
4&3=F_4&5=F_5\\
5&8=F_6&5=F_5\\
6&8=F_6&13=F_7\\
7&21=F_8&13=F_7
\end{array}$$

The number $1$ is both $F_1$ and $F_2$; for the red entries above the choice between $F_1$ and $F_2$ was made to fit the obvious pattern of the unambiguous entries.

This evidence suggests the following conjecture:

$$A_n=\begin{cases}
F_n,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
F_{n+1},&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

and

$$B_n=\begin{cases}
F_{n+1},&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
F_n,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\,.
\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

It’s easy to check that $(1)$ and $(2)$ give the correct values for $A_1,A_2,B_1$ and $B_2$, so if they satisfy the recurrences defining the sequences, they will yield the correct values of $A_n$ and $B_n$ for all $n\ge 1$.

For instance, if $(1)$ and $(2)$ hold for $1\le m\le n$, and $n$ is even, then

$$A_{n+1}=A_n+B_n=F_n+F_{n+1}=F_{n+2}\,,$$

and since in this case $n+1$ is odd, $F_{n+2}$ is exactly what $(1)$ says that $A_{n+1}$ should be. That leaves three cases to be checked: $B_{n+1}$ for even $n$, and $A_{n+1}$ and $B_{n+1}$ for odd $n$.

There are of course far more efficient ways to proceed, but sometimes even very simple tools are enough to get the job done.

Comment: I feel sorry for the downvoter, who apparently is incapable of recognizing the value of having a variety of tools available. It would be interesting to know why he or she imagines that the technique demonstrated in this answer is not useful, considering how many problems I’ve solved with it over the years.

Answer (score 0):

To start, let's write the recurrence relations in matrix form.

if n is odd:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{n + 1}\\
B_{n + 1} \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A_n \\
B_n \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

if n is even:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{n + 1}\\
B_{n + 1} \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A_n \\
B_n \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
**Claim:** $A_n = F_{n + 1}, B_n = F_{n} : \forall n \in Odd $ and $A_n = F_{n}, B_n = F_{n + 1}: \forall n \in Even$. where F is Fibonacci sequence.

**proof:** Induction.

step of induction:

if n is Odd, by applying induction hypothesis in the first equation we have:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{n + 1}\\
B_{n + 1} \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{n + 1} \\
F_{n} \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{n + 1} \\
F_{n + 2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
A_n \\
B_n \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
F_n \\
F_{n + 1} \\
\end{bmatrix}
: \forall n \in Even
$$

if n is even, by applying induction hypothesis in the second equation we have:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{n + 1}\\
B_{n + 1} \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{n} \\
F_{n + 1} \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{n + 2} \\
F_{n + 1} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
A_n \\
B_n \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{n + 1} \\
F_n \\
\end{bmatrix}
: \forall n \in Odd
$$
Base of induction:
$$ n = 1 \rightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
A_1 \\
B_1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
F_2 \\
F_1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$ n = 2 \rightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
A_2 \\
B_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
F_2 \\
F_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

always make good use of matrices in Fibonacci questions.